# Could you help me with xpath of a similar html structure?

Tags: selenium, xpath

```
<div>
    <div>
         <div>
              <h1 >text1<h1>

<div>
    <div>
         <div>
              <div>
                    <p> some text <p>
```

I would like to have the XPath for `<p>some text<p>` which follows `<h1>text1<h1>`

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon how much you know about the structure, you could make the XPath a bit more specific, and if you need to worry about whitespace decide whether you could use `=` or should use `contains()`, or normalize the whitespace with `normalize-space()` before comparing.

However, first identify the `h1` element, and then use the `following::` axis to target the `p`:

```
//h1[. = "text1"]//following::p[contains(text(), "some text")]
```

Comment: no why do you want to depend on text though ? if text change then you would have to write it again.

Comment: You can choose to remove the predicate filter constraining to those that match the value if you want. It wasn’t clear what the requirement for matching items was.

Answer (score 1):

Not totally clear if those divs the OP is showing are on the same level, but when they are and you don't want to be depend on amount of nested div's, you could use:

```
//div[.//h1[contains(text(),'text1')]]/following-sibling::div//p[contains(.,'some text')]
```

If you can depend on amount of nested divs then the following XPath wil certainly perform better

```
//div[div/div/h1[contains(text(),'text1')]]/following-sibling::div/div/div/div/p[contains(.,'some text')]
```

Answer (score 0):

In case the "some text" is unique you can simply use the following XPath

```
//p[contains(text(),'some text')]
```

or

```
//*[contains(text(),'some text')]
```

or

```
//p[text()='some text']
```

or

```
//*[text()='some text']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write Xpath of `some text` based on `text1`.

Xpath :

```
//h1[contains(text(),'text1')]/following-sibling::h1/descendant::p[last()]/preceding-sibling::p
```

Read more about xpath Axes [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp)

Answer (score -1):

This will be the xpath of the above p tag contains "some text"

```
//div//div//div//div//p
```

Comment: try to write relative xpath though.